# c++ inherit from a template struct

Tags: c++, nvcc, class-template

I have two class to define some operations and keep a record of matrix rows and cols. One for host, another for device.

```
struct device_matrix {

     device_vector<double> data;
     int row;
     int col;

     // constructors
     device_matrix() ... 

     // some matrix operations
     add()...

}


struct host_matrix {
     host_vector<double> data;
     int row;
     int col;

     // constructors
     host_matrix() ... 

     // some matrix operations
     add()...

}
```

The base class should look like:

```
template<typename T>
struct base_matrix {
    T data;
    int row;
    int col;

    // no constructors

    // some matrix operations
    add()...
}
```

But except for the type of data and constructors, other staff are the same. I have to achieve three goals, one is to specialize type T to device_vector or host_vector, another is write different constructors for both structs, and also inherit operation methods. How can I do that at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
template<template<typename T> class V>
struct base_matrix
{
    V<double> data;
    ...
    virtual void add(...) = 0;
};

struct host_matrix : base_matrix<host_vector>
{
    host_matrix() { ... }
    ...
    void add(...) { ... }
};
```

---

If you can't use a template template, then like this:

```
template<typename V>
struct base_matrix
{
    V data;
    ...
    virtual void add(...) = 0;
};

struct host_matrix : base_matrix<host_vector<double>>
{
    host_matrix() { ... }
    ...
    void add(...) { ... }
};
```

Comment: use nvcc. error: class template "thrust::host_vector" is not compatible with template template parameter "V".

Comment: Template template parameters are a solution lacking a problem. A simple type parameter would work just fine here.

Comment: Yes Alan you're right typename T is enough. Can you write an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: @user2684645 Updated answer. Note that you then have to pass the complete type (i.e. `host_vector<double>`) which I tried to avoid using the first variant.

Comment: @user2684645 Newer compilers don't need it, if you get weird errors just try to add a space.